# Part of xml message is not deserialized correctly

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Hello I have following  deserialization code

```
        public static T DeserializeXML<T>(String xml) where T : class
        {
            T newObject = null;
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StringReader sw = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                newObject = (T)s.Deserialize(sw);
            }
            return newObject;
        }
```

My message that I try to deserialize

```
<Data>
<ItemIn date="2012-08-09T10:25:54.06+01:00" itemId="000007721" Id="1">   <Extensions><Info Id="parts" order="issue"/></Extensions></ItemIn>
</Data>
```

But I just never getting `Extensions` part desirialized back to the original class I always get `null` there. Rest of the class is ok .

Any suggestions what to check ?

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class ItemTransferIn {

    private Extensions extensions;

    private System.DateTime date;

    private string itemId;

    private string Id;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ItemTransferInExtensions Extensions {
        get {
            return this.extensions;
        }
        set {
            this.extensions = value;
        }
    }

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class Extensions {

    private RecipeInfo recipeInfoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RecipeInfo RecipeInfo {
        get {
            return this.recipeInfoField;
        }
        set {
            this.recipeInfoField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class RecipeInfo {

    private string recipeIdField;

    private string orderIdField;

    private string itemBarcodeIdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Id {
        get {
            return this.recipeIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.recipeIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string order {
        get {
            return this.orderIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.orderIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string itemBarcodeId {
        get {
            return this.itemBarcodeIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemBarcodeIdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what do your DTO classes for this look like?

Answer (score 2):

For extensions... it looks like you've edited the code; there is

```
private Extensions extensions;

...

/// <remarks/>
public ItemTransferInExtensions Extensions {
    get {
        return this.extensions;
    }
    set {
        this.extensions = value;
    }
}
```

Frankly, that shouldn't even compile; we don't **have** an `ItemTransferInExtensions` class.

Also, `Info` won't work:

```
/// <remarks/>
public RecipeInfo RecipeInfo {...blah...}
```

Does not match `<Info ..../>`. So either correct the xsd and regenerate the cs, or correct the xml; but at the moment *they do not match*.

After renaming the `RecipeInfo` property to `Info` (you could also just add an attribute) and fixing the Extensions / ItemTransferInExtensions (and the missing `}`), and adding a root class to match the xml:

```
public class Data
{
    public ItemTransferIn ItemIn { get; set; }
}
```

... it all works fine:

```
static void Main()
{
    string msg = @"<Data>
<ItemIn date=""2012-08-09T10:25:54.06+01:00"" itemId=""000007721"" Id=""1"">   <Extensions><Info Id=""parts"" order=""issue""/></Extensions></ItemIn>
</Data>";
    var obj = DeserializeXML<Data>(msg);

    Console.WriteLine(obj.ItemIn.Extensions.Info.order); // issue
}
```

Frankly, though, it is easier to do it manually:

```
public class Data
{
    public ItemTransferIn ItemIn { get; set; }
}
public class ItemTransferIn
{
    [XmlAttribute("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("itemId")]
    public string Itemid { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Extensions Extensions { get; set; }
}
public class Extensions
{
    public ExtensionsInfo Info { get; set; }
}
public class ExtensionsInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("order")]
    public string Order { get; set; }
}
```